# Upload eclipse project/library for use as a gradle dependency

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, jcenter

I have a library that is being built in Eclipse, but I would like to upload it to jCenter to be used as a gradle dependency in an Android Studio project. I have tried building the gradle files in Eclipse, making a Bintray account, and trying to link it to jCenter but nothing seems to go through. It may be because I have not published it on Bintray, but I also do not see any option to publish it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [Bintray plugin](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin) to your Gradle project. Please see [the examples](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples).

Comment: However, my project is not a Gradle project, it is just a simple Java Project made in Eclipse. Is my only option to turn my Eclipse project into a Gradle project?

Comment: How do you build the project? Maven?

Comment: I am currently not using 'anything' to build the project. It is just a simple Eclipse project with java classes, compiled and built using the standard Java compiler. Maven, Gradle, etc... are therefore not used.